# Spring's "@Validated" doesn't work with Liberty and injection

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere-liberty

When I use the "@Validated" annotation in a Controller class in a Spring Boot project and run it on a Liberty server, dependency injection appears broken (it returns a NullPointerException on the line calling the injected variable). If I run the project on Tomcat, it works fine. If I comment out "@Validated" on the class and run the project on Liberty, that works too. It's only with "@Validated" and Liberty. Any ideas?

Here is my minimal reproducible example:

**TestController.java:**

```
package sr.libertyspringtest;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Validated
public class TestController {

    private TestComponent testComponent;

    public TestController(TestComponent testComponent) {
        this.testComponent = testComponent;
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    ResponseEntity<?> hello() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

        String testString = testComponent.getTestString();

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(testString);
    }
}
```

**TestComponent.java:**

```
package sr.libertyspringtest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestComponent {

    public String getTestString() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

**TestApplication.java:**

```
package sr.libertyspringtest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TestApplication.class);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

  <groupId>sr</groupId>
  <artifactId>libertyspringtest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>libertyspringtest Maven Webapp</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is with Spring Boot v2.2.7 and WebSphere Application Server Version 20.0.0.5 Liberty.

**EDIT:**
Here is the stacktrace for the NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at sr.libertyspringtest.TestController.hello(TestController.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686) ~[com.ibm.websphere.javaee.servlet.4.0_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791) ~[com.ibm.websphere.javaee.servlet.4.0_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:729) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:182) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1001) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1139) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5021) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:314) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1134) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:415) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:374) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:551) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:484) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:346) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:317) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:167) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:75) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:958) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1047) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.40.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:239) [com.ibm.ws.threading_1.1.40.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
```

Comment: What's the purpose of Validated on Class level?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli From what I understand, it's supposed to allow methods to have validation constraints in their parameters. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-validation)

Comment: Oh I see. I never used this in a service. Don't you get any exceptions when starting? Maybe this is a bug with Bean Validation and OpenLiberty

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Nope, no exceptions upon starting the server and app. It's not until I run a GET request and then it's: `[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest:1,014'
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: What's the stack look like for the NPE?

Comment: do you have a validator on the classpath `The method validation feature supported by Bean Validation 1.1 is automatically enabled as long as a JSR-303 implementation (such as Hibernate validator) is on the classpath`

Comment: @FRowe I've edited my question to add the stacktrace for the NPE.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Yes, `hibernate-validator-6.0.19.Final.jar` is on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are missing some features in your server.xml since it works on Tomcat. This might help:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>beanValidation-2.0</feature>
    <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these features were already enabled implicitly via the `javaee-8.0` feature and adding them explicitly didn't help.